# IRSSI /list Considered Harmful

Tags: irc, irssi

When I type `/list` in IRSSI, it says:

> Irssi: Doing this is not a good idea. Add -YES option to command if you really mean it

Why is it not a good idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On big networks the `LIST` command can cause large amounts of data to be dumped to the user (as of writing this post: ~820 kB on DALnet, ~1.7 MB on Freenode). In the old days, when 33 kbps dial-up was considered fast, this could cause the user to be disconnected from IRC, probably due to output buffer overflow ("SendQ exceeded") or simply not replying to `PING`s in time ("Ping timeout").

FWIW, I have never had such problems even when using 256 kbps DSL, so the warning could be considered obsolete.

Comment: When I was using IRSSI with tmux, my term began to be filled with garbage when I ran /list... is that IRSSI or tmux I wonder.

Comment: @kzh: Possibly both, possibly neither... has never happened for me, and I've used *many* combinations of terminals, multiplexers, and IRC clients.

Answer (score 3):

On big networks, the command gives a huge output. That may not be what you want for several reasons:

- This may get you disconnected from the IRC server (SendQ exceeded or Ping timeout). This is much less a problem now then it used to be. Connections are faster now, and modern servers are smarter: they don't try to send you more at once than what would fit in the queue (which would get you disconnected no matter how fast your connection is)
- It dumps a huge amount of info in your status window. That may not be something a novice user would expect from such a simple command.

Comment: Isn't "It dumps a huge amount of info in your status window" sort of the client program's fault? :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it anyone's "fault". It's not really wrong (given that almost everything in irssi is just text dumped in windows). It may just not be what the user expects...